# Interpolation Issue - ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array (Python, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, oop, interpolation

I'm a beginner in Python and I have been designing a program which reads real-life csv data on 2 stellar properties (*bv_colour_index* and *luminosity*), then interpolates linearly between the points to calculate luminosity for arbitrary values of bv_colour_index. I have not stored the output in any way, nor is my test class instance looping through small values of bv_colour_index.

The thing is, after running into some trouble with OOP (which I have only just begun to grasp), the interpolation does not work as expected, instead throwing this:

> ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

For reference,  this is my code.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from random import *


class Star:

    sun_luminosity = 3.828e+26  # W
    sun_effective_temperature = 5.772e+3  # K

    @staticmethod
    def csv_bv_colour_index_extractor():
        with open('HR_Data.csv') as hr:
            hr_read = csv.reader(hr)
            bv_index_list = []

            for column in hr_read:
                bv_index_list.append(float(column[0]))
        return bv_index_list

    @staticmethod
    def csv_luminosity_extractor():
        with open('HR_Data.csv') as hr:
            hr_read = csv.reader(hr)
            luminosity_list = []

            for column in hr_read:
                luminosity_list.append(float(column[1]))
        return luminosity_list

    def __init__(self, bv_colour_index, xp=csv_bv_colour_index_extractor, fp=csv_luminosity_extractor):
        self.bv_colour_index = bv_colour_index
        self.xp = xp
        self.fp = fp

    def calculate_luminosity(self):

        luminosity_ratio = np.interp(self.bv_colour_index, self.xp, self.fp)
        randomization_range = randint(-50, 50) / 1000
        luminosity_ratio = luminosity_ratio(1 + randomization_range)
        luminosity = luminosity_ratio * Star.sun_luminosity

        return luminosity


star = Star(2)
print(star.calculate_luminosity())
```

How can one go about solving this? As far as I've seen, there isn't a lot of documentation to help.

If there are any non-pythonian/plainly wrong techniques I have used while using OOP on this program, I would be delighted if you could point them out. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called `debugging`.  I suspect the error is raised inside one of your numpy function calls, but you are the one who has access to the **whole** error message (with traceback).  Once you identify the problem call, you try to identify the problem variable, and then examine that (and comparing that with the function documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP might be a bit of an overkill for this type of task unless you want to write a larger piece of software which would benefit from its structure. Here is my take on how you could do it:

```py
import csv
import numpy as np
import random as rand

class Star:
  # Constants as uppercase variables (class attributes)
  SUN_LUMINOSITY = 3.828e+26  # W
  SUN_EFFECTIVE_TEMPERATURE = 5.772e+3  # K

  # Define __init__ (constructor) right after the constants
  def __init__(self, file_path):
    self.file_path = file_path
    self.data = self.__load_data()
    self.randomization_range = rand.randint(-50, 50) / 1000

  # __ in front of method name indicates that it is only to be used 
  # inside of the class (encapsulation)
  def __load_data(self):
    with open(self.file_path) as csv_file:
      reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
      next(reader)  # skip header in csv file
      data = list(reader)
    return data

  def __get_and_transform_column(self, column_index):
    return [float(row[column_index]) for row in self.data]

  # @property decorator: method behaves similar to a class attribute
  # (a getter of sorts). 
  @property
  def luminosity(self):
    bv_colour_index = self.__get_and_transform_column(0)
    luminosity_values = self.__get_and_transform_column(1)
    luminosity_ratio = np.interp(self.data, 
                                 xp=bv_colour_index, 
                                 fp=luminosity_values)
    luminosity_ratio *= (1 + self.randomization_range)
    return luminosity_ratio * self.SUN_LUMINOSITY

# Initialize class with the file path
star = Star('HR_Data.csv')

# Get interpolated luminosity values
print(star.luminosity)
```